# How to kill all threads conditioned on status of on thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pool

I have `n` threads running simultaneously. These threads are processing a list containing `m` test cases. For example, thread `n-1` is working on item `m[i-1]` while thread `n` is working on item `m[i]`. I want to stop all threads if for example thread `n-1` failed or return a signal. How can I achieve this?

Here is a MWE:

This is my processing function

```
def process(input_addr):
    i =+ 1
    print('Total number of executed unit tests: {}'.format(i))
    print("executed {}. thread".format(input_addr))
    try:
        command = 'python3 '+input_addr
        result = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        msg, err = result.communicate()
        if msg.decode('utf-8') != '':
            stat = parse_shell(msg.decode('utf-8'))
            if stat:
                print('Test Failed')
                return True
        else:
            stat = parse_shell(err)                
            if stat:
                print('Test Failed')
                return True
    except Exception as e:
        print("thread.\nMessage:{1}".format(e))
```

Here is my pool:

```
def pre_run_test_files(self):
    with Pool(10) as p:
       p.map(process, self.test_files)
```

I am using:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

Comment: If you're using multiprocessing to spawn multiple processses, then you don't need to use subprocess to do multiple units of work at once.

Comment: @NickODell I am not using subprocess. Please explain more. I did not understand you.

Comment: This line uses the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module: `result = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`

Comment: @NickODell I am running a bash script using subprocess. Still I do not understand, I am not professional in python. Anyways, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Where in the MWE are the threads spawned?  I don't see it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I posted the solution.

Comment: You have your question tagged with both multithreading and multiprocessing and your question title and text refers to *threads* but your import statement indicates you are actually using processes. You should really edit your question and make this clearer. It would also be clearer if you presented a minimal, reproducible example as a single source file rather than in 3 separate pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your worker function, `process` simply raise an exception and use an *error_callback* function with `apply_async` that calls `terminate` on the pool as in the following demo:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process(i):
    import time

    time.sleep(1)
    if i == 6:
        raise ValueError(f'Bad value: {i}')
    print(i, flush=True)

def my_error_callback(e):
    pool.terminate()
    print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(4)
    for i in range(20):
        pool.apply_async(process, args=(i,), error_callback=my_error_callback)
    # wait for all tasks to complete
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Prints:

```
0
1
3
2
4
5
7
Bad value: 6
```

You should be able to adapt the above code to your particular problem.

**Update**

Because your original code used the `map` method, there is a second solution that use methid `imap_unordered`, which will returns an iterator that on every iteration returns the next return value from your worker function, `process`, or raises an exception if your worker function raised an exception. With method `imap_unordere` these results are returned *in an arbitrary completion order* rather than in *task submission order*, but when the default *chunksize* argument of 1 is used, this *arbitrary* order is typically task-completion order. This is what you want so that you can detect an exception at the earliest possible time and terminate the pool. Of course, if you cared about the return values from `process`, then you would use method `imap` so that the results are returned in task-submission order. But in that case if when case i == 6 is when the exception is raised but that task happened to be the first task to complete, its exception could still not be returned until the tasks submitted for i == 1 though 5 were completed.

In the following code a pool size of 8 is used, and all tasks first sleep for 1 second before printing their arguments and returning *except* for the case of i == 6, which raises an exception immediately. Using `imap_unordered` we have:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process(i):
    import time

    # raise an exception immediately for i == 6 without sleeping
    if (i != 6):
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Bad value: {i}')
    print(i, flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(8)
    results = pool.imap_unordered(process, range(20))
    try:
        # Iterate results as task complete until
        # we are done or one raises an exeption:
        for result in results:
            # we don't care about the return value:
            pass
    except Exception as e:
        pool.terminate()
        print(e)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Prints:

```
Bad value: 6
```

If we replace the call to `imap_unordered` with a call to `imap`, then the output is:

```py
0
1
2
3
4
5
Bad value: 6
```

The first solution, using `apply_async` with a *error_callback* argument, allows for the exception to be acted upon as soon as it occurs *and* if you care about the results in task submission order, you can save the `multiprocessing.AsyncResult` objects returned by `apply_async` in a list and call `get` on these objects. Try the following code with `RAISE_EXCEPTION` set to `True` and then to `False`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

RAISE_EXCEPTION = True

def process(i):
    if RAISE_EXCEPTION and i == 6:
        raise ValueError(f'Bad value: {i}')
    time.sleep(1)
    return i # instead of printing

def my_error_callback(e):
    global got_exception

    got_exception = True
    pool.terminate()
    print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    got_exception = False
    pool = Pool(4)
    async_results = [pool.apply_async(process, args=(i,), error_callback=my_error_callback) for i in range(20)]
    # Wait for all tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    if not got_exception:
        for async_result in async_results:
            print(async_result.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
def process(i, input_addr, event):
    kill_flag = False
    if not event.is_set():
        print('Total number of executed unit tests: {}'.format(i))
        print("executed {}. thread".format(input_addr))
        try:
            command = 'python3 '+input_addr
            result = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            msg, err = result.communicate()
            if msg.decode('utf-8') != '':
                stat = parse_shell(msg.decode('utf-8'))
                if stat:
                    print('Test Failed')
                    kill_flag = True
                    # all_run.append(input_addr)
                    #write_list_to_txt(input_addr, valid_tests)
                else:
                    kill_flag = False
            else:
                stat = parse_shell(err)                
                if stat:
                    print('Test Failed')
                    kill_flag = True
                    # all_run.append(input_addr)
                    #write_list_to_txt(input_addr, valid_tests)
                else:
                    kill_flag = False
        except Exception as e:
            print("thread.\nMessage:{1}".format(e))
    if kill_flag:
        event.set()
```

```
def manager():
     p= multiprocessing.Pool(10) 
     m = multiprocessing.Manager()
     event = m.Event()
     for i,f in enumerate(self.test_files):
         p.apply_async(process, (i, f, event))
     p.close()
     event.wait()
     p.terminate()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).